# Change Current View html code on click controller call MVC (SPA)

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have MVC project, and i want to change content (html code) on the current page.

The page contains table with rows. When i click some button, i want:

1. clear table completely, remove all `<tr>`
2. controller get data by some id
3. insert new rows (`<tr>`) in the table with data my controller returned

The main thing, i don't want to redirect to other page or reload the page. Only change html content.

Basically i am talking about SPA. I am curious if it is possible to maintain everything mainly with controllers, razor, taghelpers or anything else but JS functions calling back-end methods to return HTML content. Or at least i would like to know the best (save) option to do this kind of actions with MVC .net core.

Comment: It sounds like the technology you're looking for is "AJAX".  With AJAX you can write client-side code to make HTTP requests to the server-side code (in this case controller actions) and handle the responses.  So you can have actions which just return JSON data, and your JavaScript code can make requests and receive that data, updating the page as needed.  Your favorite search engine can help you find many tutorials and examples on using AJAX in ASP.NET MVC.  The framework or 3rd party tools could have pre-built functionality for you, and you can write your own in plain JavaScript.

Comment: Agreed - tag helpers are really a server-side rendering model. Either you choose the standard GET/POST model, or as suggested above, perform your GET, then use AJAX calls to GET any other resources and POST to save/delete data. You can either return the raw data and perform conversion into HTML at the client in Javascript, or return HTML from the AJAX call and simply insert that text into the required element. Wither method is acceptable - your call on which one you think is appropriate